# ¿Como enviar el ID de un elemento en una view a un controlador?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Lo que quiero hacer es que al dar click sobre el nombre del curso muestre una etiqueta p o div y me muestre los detalles del curso.

Por medio de un array asociativo envió resultados de consultas de mi BD, a mi view. Dentro del array va un resultado llamado "cursos" este me envia 3 columnas "idcurso", "curso", "horario". Del cual solo imprimo la columna "cursos" en la view.

Ahora tengo un stored procedure que recibe como parámetro el "idcurso" y arroja los detalles del curso.
Hasta el momento con JavaScript al hacer click sobre el nombre del curso tomo el "idcurso" mediante un console.log logro ver el idcurso. Sin embargo no logro enviar el idcurso a mi controlador donde está el stored que posteriormente enviara el resultado a la misma view y me mostrara sus resultados.
Esta es mi view donde se muestra en una tabla los nombres de cursos

```
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($cursos as $curso)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="nombre" data-idcurso="{{ $curso->idcurso}}">{{$curso->curso}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Este es el codigo en JavaScript que toma el idcurso

```
var nombres = document.querySelectorAll('.nombre');
    nombres.forEach(function(nombre) {
    nombre.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var idcarga = this.getAttribute('data-idcurso');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/detalles');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {

        console.log(idcurso);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {


    };
    xhr.send('idcarga=' + encodeURIComponent(idcurso) + '&_token=' + encodeURIComponent('{{ csrf_token() }}'));
});
```

});

En la linea donde esta: xhr.open('GET', '/detalles'); es donde coloco mi ruta al controlador  que contienen la funcion donde ejecuto mi stored procedure.

Comment: hola segun ChatGPT dice que lo estas haciendo mal.... no veo el envio del IDCurso al backend ... https://chat.openai.com/share/5525bb60-42cd-468a-a678-5f740e84ae84

Comment: creo conveniente hacer un repaso sobre la lógica, ya que si no te está devolviendo los datos o no los estas pintando muy probablemente te faltan cosas que integrar a tu logica/codigo.

Comment: ¡Hola, gracias! Y si era mi lógica que no estaba bien, cambié algunas cosas y logré hacer lo que necesitaba.